# ROS Unknown CMake command "ecl_detect_filesystem"

Tags: cmake, ros, ecl

I am new to ROS and I was given a workspace, which I need to compile and use for a university project. When trying to compile this workspace with **catkin_make**, I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_filesystem/CMakeLists.txt:18   
(ecl_detect_filesystem):
Unknown CMake command "ecl_detect_filesystem".
```

Here is the complete output:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/celsoluiz81/ros_catkin_ws/fendt_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/celsoluiz81/ros_catkin_ws/fendt_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/celsoluiz81/ros_catkin_ws/fendt_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 30 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - ecl_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ecl_command_line
-- ~~  - ecl_eigen
-- ~~  - ecl_exceptions
-- ~~  - ecl_filesystem
-- ~~  - ecl_mpl
-- ~~  - ecl_time
-- ~~  - ecl_ipc
-- ~~  - ecl_type_traits
-- ~~  - ecl_concepts
-- ~~  - ecl_converters
-- ~~  - ecl_formatters
-- ~~  - ecl_linear_algebra
-- ~~  - ecl_math
-- ~~  - ecl_statistics
-- ~~  - ecl_utilities
-- ~~  - ecl_containers
-- ~~  - ecl_geometry
-- ~~  - ecl_threads
-- ~~  - ecl_devices
-- ~~  - ecl_sigslots
-- ~~  - ecl_streams
-- ~~  - ecl_core_apps
-- ~~  - comm
-- ~~  - geometry_helpers
-- ~~  - odom
-- ~~  - path_planner
-- ~~  - path_controller
-- ~~  - task_controller
-- ~~  - gazebo_simulation
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ecl_core'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_core)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ecl_command_line'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_command_line)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ecl_eigen'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_eigen)
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ecl_exceptions'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_exceptions)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'ecl_filesystem'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_filesystem)
CMake Error at ecl_core/src/ecl_core/ecl_filesystem/CMakeLists.txt:18 (ecl_detect_filesystem):
Unknown CMake command "ecl_detect_filesystem".
```

I have tried installing the package ecl_filesystem using **apt-get**, but it was not available to be installed via repository.

The ecl_filesystem files seem to be present in the workspace that I am trying to build, but I can't find them anywhere in my ROS installation under /op/ros/indigo.

I am sure this is a simple problem to solve, but none of my attempts have succeeded so far. I believe cmake is only looking in my ROS installation directory for the packages and not locally in my workspace.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this problem? I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add the content of the `CMakeLists.txt` that is causing the error? I would like to see in which context this unknown command is used.

Comment: @luator Thanks a lot for getting back to me. I ended up finding the error. Somehow I had a stray copy of ecl-core package in my /home/celsoluiz81/ros_catkin_ws/fendt_ws/devel folder. I think I mistakenly cloned it there from github at some point. Anyway, removing this folder, erasing the devel, build and install directories and then running **catkin_make** again did the trick for me.